Why Does x509Store.Certificates.Find Return an Empty Collection Even When the Certificate Exists?
I have an X509Certificate stored in the certificate store under my system account, which I have verified visually using Run -> mmc.
The following code displays my certificate successfully:
using (var x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
 {
     x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

     X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection1 = x509Store.Certificates;

     Console.WriteLine($"Listing all available certificates count: {certificateCollection1.Count}");

     foreach (var certificate2 in certificateCollection1)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {certificate2.Subject}");
         Console.WriteLine($"Issuer: {certificate2.Issuer}");
         Console.WriteLine($"Thumbprint: {certificate2.Thumbprint}");
         Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
  

However, when I use either of the following methods:
certificateCollection = x509Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, certificate2.Subject, true);

or
certificateCollection = x509Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certificate2.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false), true);

and then when i try to display my certificatecollection property the count is 0
Console.WriteLine($"Listing all available internal certificates count: {certificateCollection.Count}");
writer.WriteLine($"Listing all available internal certificates count: {certificateCollection.Count}");

I'm using the same subject name or certificate name to display the list of certificates, but it returns 0. This works fine on my machine, but when the same code is deployed to production machines, some of them unable to find the certificate. When a certificate is present on a machine and using the same name to find (I’m sure I have not misspelled as I'm using the same variable returned by X509Certificate2Collection), it returns an empty collection.
I would like to understand what im doing wrong with the x509Store.Certificates.Find method.

Did you try passing false as the last parameter?

One of the reasons is that X509Certificate2Collection.Find(X509FindType, Object, Boolean) method's last parameter validOnly is set to true. If your cert's chain is invalid, then method will return nothing. Try to set last parameter to false and see if there will be a difference in results.

Thanks, the certifcate started displaying after setting false. The system time was wriong and not matching with certificate validity

In fact, the system is correct. Your certificate is untrusted or otherwise invalid.
